# Fusing multiple web servers into one site

Tags: html, ajax, web, frames

Where I work, we use a multitude of various services such as Confluence, JIRA, Bamboo, Mercurial, and various others, that all have a web interface that our engineers can access through the corporate intranet.

However, many in our staff aren't directly network wizzes and having these services spread out confuses them. What I want to do is to set up a central server from which they can branch out and find all other web interfaces that relate to their work.

The first thought i had was to create a light web page with frames, using a top bar where the user can quick-navigate to any of the services available - but this creates an additional problem where i can't email someone a direct link to a page within a service, because it will remove that frame (and confusion will arise again when they see there's no way to navigate by clicks).

Is there some best practice to put this all together? Some hints? ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, stay far far away from frames. They annoy users something fierce (partially because of that not-able-to-bookmark issue you just spoke of.)

You could create a small webpage that could load within a popup window, which contained dropdown-nav links to all of the various tools. If you had the resources, you could even make it so that users could customize this window - so that they can add bookmarks to the tools they use the most.

But that does bring up the question...I'm guessing your staff isn't savvy enough users to know how to use bookmarks? Or keep going to a central link-repository page? Whatever solution you're thinking of, get input from a sampling of your user base, and find out how they'd actually prefer to work. They're the ones who are going to be using the tools, after all. Keep them involved, solicit their input, do "hallway usability tests" or any tool you end up building might be as useful as a chocolate teapot.